# Некорректно распечатывается PictureBox.Image

Tags: c#, print

```
private void печатьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument document = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        document.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Print);
        printDialog.Document = document;

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            document.Print();
        }
    }

    private void Print(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(PB_Plan.Image.Width, PB_Plan.Image.Height);
        PB_Plan.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, PB_Plan.Image.Width, PB_Plan.Image.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

Помогите исправить код, чтобы документ распечатывался на весь лист.
PB_Plan.SizeMode = StretchImage.

[image: Результат печати]

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено. Вдруг кому понадобится. Всё идеально работает.

```
private void печатьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // показываем окно настройки печати
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
            dlg.Document = printDoc;
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
                printDoc.Print();
            }
    }

    private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(PB_Plan.Image, Point.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[Свойство PageSettings.PaperSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Comment: нашел. DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize, меняю размер, ничего не меняется при печати..

Comment: верно, измените размер изображения относительно целевого размера листа.

Comment: document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("", 210, 297);
ничего не меняется. ставил другие размеры, ничего не меняется.